# Pipeline pow operator issue with

Tags: .net, f#

i want to write the next function using pipeline:

```
A = 1/Sum[1-k](x^2)
```

so when i write:

```
//Adaptive step
let a_Adaptive x =
    x
    |> Array.map (fun x -> x ** 2.0)
    |> Array.sum
    |> (**) -1.0
```

f# interpretes `(**)` as a multiline comment, but i want use it as a function.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to check out work-in-progress data frame library that I'm working on at Blue Mountian: https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/FSharp.DataFrame Using the `Series` type, you should be able to write just: `1.0/(Series.sum (x ** 2.0))` (it provides overloaded operators for "series" data structure)

Comment: In case your monday morning started with debugging a strange bug ;) ( ** ) -1.0 is probably not what you want. That becomes (-1)**x, while you need x**(-1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to add a space before the `**`:

```
let a_Adaptive x =
    x
    |> Array.map (fun x -> x ** 2.0)
    |> Array.sum
    |> ( ** ) -1.0
```

From the F# specification:

> To define other operators that begin with `*`, whitespace must follow
>   the opening parenthesis; otherwise `(*` is interpreted as the start of a
>   comment:
>
> let ( *+* ) x y = (x + y)